# Using the word "impressive" with a condition

Tags: grammar

I want to say "it is impressive given that he/she did it only in 10 min" in an informal and short form. Is it correct to stay "impressive for a 10-min-work"? Thanks.

Comment: *Work* won't take an indefinite article here. *Impressive for ten minute's work*. It might sound dismissive, but I can't tell without context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could say, "It is impressive (that) she did it in only ten minutes." That's what I would say if she she carried out an extremely difficult task, or solved an extremely difficult problem, in ten minutes when most people would have taken longer. You don't need to say *given that*, although there's nothing grammatically wrong with doing so. The choice may depend on your context.

It is incorrect to say "impressive for a 10-minute work". Agree with @deadrat's comment in its entirety.